# How to access the parameter sent from render page inside each loop in handlebar page?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, foreach, handlebars.js

I am sending parameter `hiding:true` with this below code.

Express code:

```
 res.render('viewTask',{mainData: element, hiding: true});
```

Handlebar Code:

This is the code for accessing the `hiding parameter` in handlebar page with `if` condition. But with `each loop` the value of `hiding` is setting as `false` I don't know why. When I use it on another element single time not inside loop; its working.

```
{{#each mainData.Bigpaths}}
    <br>
    <div class="displayThumbnails">
      <img src="/images/download-card-image.svg" class="file-thumbnail" width="75" height="50">
      {{#if hiding}}
      <a href="removeThumbnail/{{this.Id4AddtasksBigpaths}}/{{this.uniqueId}}" class="imag-close"></a>
      {{/if}}
    <span>{{this.name}}</span>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
```

So my question is how to access the render page parameters inside loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are sending a variable to a render function and is available only during rendering the page, once the page is rendered and sent to the client it will not be available. What you can do is, during the rendering stage, you can assign the variable value to a new variable in javascript tags and make use of it.

```
<script>
  var hidingVar = "{{ hiding }}";
  console.log(hidingVar);
</script>
```

Comment: But how can i use this inside handlebar page? Since it wont be accessible inside JS code. ?

Comment: It is a javascript variable, obviously, you can use it in the handlebar page. Just like the javascript object property "mainData.Bigpaths" that you used in the handlebar page.  We are creating a new javascript variable called "hidingVar" at the render time which can be used in place of "hiding" as you used above. 
In your case, you need to create this "hidingVar" javascript variable in "viewTask" page which you are trying to render.